# as3 can't set checkbox label - need to know when it is loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

We have a fla, and under "Advanced Actionscript Settings", we have

"Automatically declare stage instances"

UNchecked.

We then have a bunch of these declarations at the class level of our document class:

```
public var spouseCheck:CheckBox;
```

If I set spouseCheck.label = "blah" in my constructor, it does not work. However, if I set it later, (when another event happens), it does work.  This implies that the checkbox is completely loaded at that time. How can I put an event listener on the checkbox so that I will know when it is completely loaded, and I can set the label?  thanks!

Comment: in your constructor, try doing `this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);`  then do your .label = blah in there (the init function you'll create), (and remove the event listener)

Comment: LD_MS, worked great (except 'this' should be 'spouseCheck' in my case). If you answer the question formally, I will check it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of the class where you set `spouseCheck.label = "blah"`, remove that line and add this line:

```
spouseCheck.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
```

Then create the init function:

```
function init(e:Event):void {
    spouseCheck.label = "blah";
    spouseCheck.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
}
```

That event is triggered when spouseCheck is on the displayList (stage) and should ensure it's ready.

Comment: This is nice, thanks! In my recent AIR app this doesnt however help, for some reason. I ended up also adding a timer inside init function (200ms or so) and after timer completes, I run next lines of code. In my case the problem was "loading screen" not being visible (via addChild) while app builds components for next page. Any other ideas than using timer like I now do?

Comment: @kaarto - Hard to help without seeing code.  Consider asking a new question with all your details.