# AS3 How to wait for child component to load?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components

I have a movieclip, we can call it "mc". On my "mc" is a textarea component called "childta". I am creating instances of "mc" with stage.addchild. All is well and going good but when I add a line of code after that to set the text of "childta" it doesnt show up due to the code being executed prior to it being loaded.

I do know I have the code right because if i click the button to set the text of "childta" it does work. So how can I wait for mc.childta to be loaded?

```
               var mcPM:PMBox = new PMBox();
               pmwaiting = 1;
                mcPM.name = sendername;
                stage.addChild(mcPM);
                mcPM.x = 200;
                mcPM.y = 200;
                mcPM.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, pmloaded);
                           }
           while(pmwaiting == 1) {

           }
            MovieClip(stage.getChildByName(sendername)).pmsa.addText(dArray[3]);
            mcPM.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, pmloaded);
       }
   } else {
        //Its chat text, add to window
        sa.addText(e.data);
   }
}
function pmloaded(Event):void {
    pmwaiting = 0;

}
```

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504345/as3-cant-set-checkbox-label-need-to-know-when-it-is-loaded/12505059#12505059

Comment: your while loop will cause a stackoverflow,  though maybe having it empty of code causes the runtime to exit it.  Where is `childta`? inside `mcPM`?  if so, post your `PMBox` class code.   Also, your mcPM added to stage listener should be added before you do stage.addChild(mcPM)

Comment: PMBox is a movie clip. With a textfield which is what pmsa is. It is SmileArea located at http://www.valentin-manthei.de/as3/SmileArea.as I CAN set text of a normal textfield but not the smilearea one. All I can guess is its sending the addtext prior to the smilearea (pmsa) being loaded. I will try to move the event listener now. any other suggestions? been at this all day, and thank you!

Comment: Now if I click the button again, it does send the text properly. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening for "`ADDED_TO_STAGE`"

```
childta = new TextArea();
childta.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,childtaLoaded);

function childtaLoaded(e:Event):void {
    //ready to work with
}

addChild(childta);
```

Comment: Ive added that code above still no luck. Yes, pmwaiting is a global variable

Comment: I can get that to trigger when mcPM (the movie clip itself) loads. But in that event Im still getting the 1009 error.